# Unable to acquire a connection from driver [null], user [null] and URL [null]. / EclipseLink 1.2 / Spring 2.5.6 / OSGI

Tags: spring, jpa, osgi, eclipselink

I try to deploy a project where EclipseLink JPA is used as ORM tool on an OSGI platform. The project works fine when running outside of a OSGI container.

Version used : Spring 2.5.6, EclipseLink 1.2.0

Unfortunately, I get this error on the OSGI platform :

```
Exception Description: Unable to acquire a connection from driver [null], user [null] and URL [null].  Verify that you have set the expected driver class and URL.  Check your login, persistence.xml or sessions.xml resource.  The jdbc.driver property should be set to a class that is compatible with your database platform
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:434)
    at $Proxy152.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:190)
    at $Proxy153.find(Unknown Source)
```

For an unknown reason the datasource which is created and added to the org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean is not retrieved by EclipseLink

Any idea is welcome ?

Kind regards,

charles

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that database property file is in the classpath?

Make sure it is there.

Answer (score 0):

See,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples#OSGi_Examples

Ensure you DataSource is accessible and all of your OSGi and Spring configuration is correct.